# Excel formula- Two or more different cells repeat same text

Tags: excel

I need help with a formula.
In Column A I have a list of numbers or text.
In column B, I have another list of numbers or text, but for example in cell B 10 is the same  a number or text as in cell A55. I need a formula in column C10 that will show that the cells B10 and A55 same.

Columns A and B contain different data (text or numbers) but there is a possibility that in column B may be repeated as the data in column A.
In A column I have about 250 different data in column B  maximum of 15, so I need a formula for Column C that will indicate if a value in column B repeats.

I need a formula for excel 2003

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the row number of the first object found in Column A which is repeated in a cell of column B.

=IFERROR(MATCH(B1,A:A,0),"")

[image]

With your figures:

[image]

Comment: In colum A I have Nombers:214743
214597
214766
214660
214762
214763
214759
214777
214775
214778
214781
214117
214779
214791
214773
214662
214792
214795
214757
214752
214797
214765
214788
214153
214568
214742
214747
, In colum B I have numbers :214865
214773
215022
215035
215021
215025
214747

Comment: I didnt explain good, and I want to know if for expl No 214747 repeat itself in colum A

Comment: That is exactly what I did propose you. In column C you have the line in which the cell B is repeated in column A. I attach you a picture. If you what just a leyend you can change for this =IF(IFERROR(MATCH(B2,A:A,0),"")="","NO DUPLICATED","DUPLICATED")

Comment: thank you, but I still have a problem. If I type in cell C1 the formula =IFERROR(MATCH(B1,A:A,0),"") , excell not accept. In cell C1 is written  #NAME?
The same is repeated with a different formula-=IF(IFERROR(MATCH(B2,A:A,0),"")="","NO DUPLICATED","DUPLICATED")